# How do you style/select inline-block elements in the first row when in a flexible container?

Tags: html, css

I understand this may be impossible with pure CSS but... how can I select just the nth row of from a set of elements - ***when*** these elements are in a flexible width container and the elements themselves are `inline-block`;

Examples:

- A container of 10 elements, each 50px wide, and the container is 200px wide - the selector would grab elements 1 thru 4 (element 5 onwards have been wrapped on the next line)
- A container of 10 elements, each 50px wide, and the container is 250px wide - the selector would grab elements 1 thru 5 (element 6 onwards have been wrapped on the next line)

Note: Please refer to this fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/y7qCJ/ - but obviously nth-child doesn't work like this, and hence my question is here.

Comment: Seems a bit stupid to ask this but a) do you have control of the html b) is it serverside generated and does it ever change c) are you looking for the manual selectors or a javascript solution?

Comment: Yes I do have control over the HTML but the content is dynamic (yes server side) and the content can be presented on a variety of widths (ie sometimes the container is 100px, sometimes 900px) this is only know at the client side (so server is out). JS might very well be a fallback, but I'd prefer CSS. In saying that, no it's not possible with CSS is a valid answer

Comment: It is possible with css... the only consideration is that as your page can change you will have to autogenerate the css also to target the right depth of css rules to match the html that has been generated - see my answer

Comment: `.container:first-line` will cheaply grab the first line for you since they're all inline blocks, but that's about as far as you can go without generated code.

Comment: Yep and looking further at your use case I think you (as it is fluid) will have to rely on javascript to .onresize calc to the container width, divide by 50, .abs the result and then iterate the lis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - can't be done with CSS

Answer (score 0):

nth child is not cross browser so you are back to manually selecting:

```
.container > li:first-child,
.container > li:first-child+li,
.container > li:first-child+li+li,
.container > li:first-child+li+li+li,
.container > li:first-child+li+li+li+li
{
   border:1px solid red; 
}
```

which will target first 5 obviously. If your html is server generated then you could also tack some inline server-side generated css into the head to add this rule (as it is changeable) but if your html will never change then you can just add it to the .css as normal.

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7qCJ/1/)

UPDATE:

As you seem to be wanting the amount of LIs targetted to be dependent on the width of the browser in a FLUID layout you will have to do a javascript solution for which the psuedo code is:

```
on load/resize

  lielements[] = .container > li
  width = get .container width
  licount = abs(width/50)

  for(int i = 1; i < licount; ++i)
  {
     lielements[i].css = apply css class with width:50px to element
  }
```